# How to detect android phone ring and vibrate programmatically?

Tags: android, volume

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

switch (am.getRingerMode()) {
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT:
        Log.i("MyApp","Silent mode");
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE:
        Log.i("MyApp","Vibrate mode");
        break;
    case AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL:
        Log.i("MyApp","Normal mode");
        break;
}
```

From above code only detect only one mode. but i want to check 2 mode either ring+vibrate or silent+vibrate.

How it is possible?

Comment: `RINGER_MOODE_VIBRATE` will give you your `silent+vibrate` condition

Answer (score 2):

There is no any method to get ring+vibrate and silent+vibrate. As we know that we have three method to get ringer mode.

```
AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL
AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT
AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE
```

So , You just have to create a method to check condition for both ring and vibrate

Like ring+vibrate.

```
public boolean statusRingVibrate(){
        boolean status = false;
        AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if(am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL && am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE){
            status = true;
        }       
        return status;      
    }
```

Comment: only detect one mode normal by default. always false return.

Comment: Have u checked this scenario, I think both will return true :)

Comment: hey Samsad... I have a small doubt in this... If the phone is both ringing and vibrating what value we will be getting if we call the "getRingerMode()" because either it has to send "1 -> RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE" or "2 -> RINGER_MODE_NORMAL".

Comment: If the phone is both ringing and vibrating then this getRingerMode() method will return true value.

Comment: This will always return false. You want to use OR.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and combine some method together:

```
public static boolean checkVibreationIsOn(Context context){
    boolean status = false;
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if(am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE){
        status = true;
    } else if (1 == Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), "vibrate_when_ringing", 0)) //vibrate on
        status = true;
    return status;
}

public static boolean checkRingerIsOn(Context context){
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    return am.getRingerMode() == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Please follow the [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)

RINGER_MODE_NORMAL : Ringer mode that may be audible and may vibrate. It will be audible if the volume before changing out of this mode was audible. It will vibrate if the vibrate setting is on.

RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE : Ringer mode that will be silent and will vibrate. (This will cause the phone ringer to always vibrate, but the notification vibrate to only vibrate if set.)

So AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL i.e., '2' will be returned if the phone is either vibrating or ringing. And it will return AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE i.e., '1' if the phone is in silent and vibrating.